# Using member of template class to instantiate template default parameter in MSVC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

The following piece of code is a reduced sample from the large project I'm trying to port from GCC/G++ to Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.  It compiles fine with G++, but with MSVC++, it throws errors, and I'm having trouble understanding why.

```
template <typename A, typename B = typename A::C::D>    // line 1
struct foo
{
  typedef int type;
};

template <template <typename> class E, typename T>
typename foo<E<T> >::type                               // line 8
bar(){}
```

The error messages from MSVC++ are:

```
example1.cpp(1) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'E<T>'
example1.cpp(8) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'D'
example1.cpp(8) : error C2065: 'D' : undeclared identifier
```

I've tried a few changes to narrow down the problem a bit, and while I don't fully understand it, here's what I've discovered: If in line 1 I replace `A::C::D` with `A::C`, it works fine.  If I replace `template <typename> class E` with just `typename E` and make that `foo<E>`, it works fine.  If explicitly specify the second template argument to `foo` in line 8, like so, it works fine:

```
typename foo<E<T>, typename E<T>::C::D>::type          // line 8
```

And, if I replace the use of `A::C::D` with something innocuous like `typename B = A` in line 1, but add a different use of `A::C::D` as `typedef typename A::C::D qux;` to the definition of `foo`, that also works fine.

Any ideas?  What bit of C++ rules am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered reporting a bug? These "suspicious situations when the bug doesn't appear" indicate it would be right. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: I have, but I want to be sure it's actually a bug first -- I've run into several things like this before where it turned out I was missing something like a need for a `typename` due to an obscure corner of C++ syntax.  Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: For the record, I ended up filing this as a bug; Thanks for the link to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this as a bug with Microsoft as per jpalecek's suggestion, and Microsoft has confirmed that it is indeed a fault in their compiler:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/576196